# Simple nav bar in css issues, probably a really easy answer

Tags: html, css

so im just trying to make a simple nav bar menu that has a 4px border under it when you hover over it. This in itself isn't hard to do, but im trying to style it so that the different menu elements are in different colours. this is what I have so far:

HTML

```
    <div id="navcontainer">
<ul id="navlist">
<li id="active"><a href="#" class="home">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="about">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>

</ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
/*Menu*/

#navlist
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 20px 10px;
}

#navlist ul, #navlist li
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}

#navlist a:link, #navlist a:visited
{
float: left;
line-height: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0 10px 4px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #999;
}
#navlist a:hover { color: #000; }

#navlist  li .home {
color: #d43f3f;
}

#navlist li .home a:hover
{
border-bottom: 4px solid #d43f3f;
padding-bottom: 2px;
background: transparent;
color: #d43f3f;
}
#navlist li .about {
color: #00ace9;
}

#navlist  li .about a:hover
{
border-bottom: 4px solid #00ace9;
padding-bottom: 2px;
background: transparent;
color: #00ace9;
}
#navlist li .portfolio {
color: #6a9a19;
}

#navlist li .portfolio a:hover
{
border-bottom: 4px solid #6a9a19;
padding-bottom: 2px;
background: transparent;
color: #6a9a19;
}
```

It shows the different colours but the hover feature isnt working with my 4px border... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was really simple. You have two declarations in your CSS.

`#navlist li .portfolio a:hover {`

`.portfolio` IS the `a` element. The declaration you've used implies: `a` which is child of `.portfolio` which is child of `li` which is child of `#navlist`. You've gone too deep.

This will work:

`#navlist li a.portfolio:hover {`

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jnbBz/1/

Full corrected CSS:

```
/*Menu*/

#navlist
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0 0 20px 10px;
}

#navlist ul, #navlist li
{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
display: inline;
list-style-type: none;
}

#navlist a:link, #navlist a:visited
{
float: left;
line-height: 14px;
font-weight: bold;
margin: 0 10px 4px 10px;
text-decoration: none;
color: #999;
}
#navlist a:hover { color: #000; }

#navlist  li .home {
color: #d43f3f;
}

#navlist li .home:hover
{
border-bottom: 4px solid #d43f3f;
padding-bottom: 2px;
background: transparent;
color: #d43f3f;
}
#navlist li .about {
color: #00ace9;
}

#navlist  li .about:hover
{
border-bottom: 4px solid #00ace9;
padding-bottom: 2px;
background: transparent;
color: #00ace9;
}
#navlist li .portfolio {
color: #6a9a19;
}

#navlist li a.portfolio:hover
{
border-bottom: 4px solid #6a9a19;
padding-bottom: 2px;
background: transparent;
color: #6a9a19;
}
```

Comment: LOL feeling a bit of a noob right now... but thank you... its too late in the evening :D

Comment: need more coffee ;) it's hard to pick it out if you've been working at it too long. Accept if it solves your problem puh-lease ;)

Answer (score 1):

You have your selectors wrong

`#navlist li .about` should be `#navlist li a.about` for example